# using a cron job to automatically backup the same drive using dd

Tags: cron, backup, dd

so I want to backup my <s>system</s> drive (full drive not just partition) every month using dd, in an external hard drive. So I have something like this in my crontab

```
0 9 1 * *   dd if=/dev/sda | gzip -c > /mnt/5E13119070E2D202/Backups/system_drive.backup.img.gz
```

And that works fine. But I am trying to figure out how to replace /dev/sda (system drive) with something which is persistent between reboots.

Using `blkid` (trimmed):

```
/dev/sda5: UUID="58141b62-72af-463c-a3c3-57d0b739c632" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="c1b89110-05"
/dev/sda1: UUID="a97d9b38-e8a6-4cc2-9684-b7e579c1a990" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="c1b89110-01"
/dev/sdg1: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="5E13119070E2D202" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="000b4ae7-01"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: yes, /dev/disk/by-uuid/…

Comment: also, `gzip` is a very unfortunate choice as compressor here: it's algorithm is old, slow and not very good at compressing. You could use `pigz` which at least uses multiple threads to speed things up. But realistically, you want to use something like `zstd -7 -T0` to achieve the same speed as gzip achieves while getting typically around twice the compression.

Comment: also, absolutely no need for `dd`; you can just `gzip < /dev/disk/by-uuid/58… > /mnt/backup/system_drive.img.gzip` (or, better, `zstd -7 -T0 < /dev/disk/by-uuid/58… > /mnt/backup/system_drive.img.zstd`)

Comment: Why would the name of your system drive change between reboots?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, he said he doesn't want to backup a specific partition, but the full drive. /dev/disk/by-uuid only has links to the partitions.

Comment: @aviro fair point!

Comment: @aviro see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I am trying to figure out how to replace /dev/sda (system drive) with something which is persistent between reboots.

So, you need a "world wide unique name" for your whole disk. Luckily, Linux has you covered.

1. Find out the unique name for your drive by finding the right `wwn-*` entry in /dev/disk/by-id. You could just `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-*`and look for `sda`, or do something like `find /dev/disk/by-id -name 'wwn-*' -lname '*/sda'`. Either way, you get a symlink like /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x1234cafe.
2. in your script,

```bash
devlink=/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x1234cafe

gzip < "${devlink}" > /mnt/5E13119070E2D202/Backups/system_drive.backup.img.gz
```

as there's literally no advantage to using `dd` here. Quite the contrary! Instead inserting `dd` with its own block sizes and potential copy overhead, just let the compressor do its work directly on input.

I do recommend you do not use `gzip` for that, for two reasons:

1. it's algorithm is old, slow and not very good at compressing.
2. it's single-threaded, putting another bottleneck atop of the already slow algorithm

You could, instead of `gzip`, at least use `pigz`, which is multithreaded and does the same. But, while I have much respect for Adler and his compressors, it's been a couple of decades, and modern compressors are both faster and better at compressing; so this would fare better on both speed and compression ratio fronts

```bash
#!/bin/sh
devlink=/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x1234cafe
zstd -5 -T0 --force -- "${devlink}" > /mnt/5E13119070E2D202/Backups/system_drive.backup.img.gz
#    ^  ^    ^       ^  ^
#    |  |    |       |  |
#    \-------------------- -5: use a medium-low compression ratio. 
#       |    |       |  |      still better than `gzip --best`, typically, but also faster.
#       |    |       |  |      Possible values are 1 to 18, where you typically see
#       |    |       |  |      diminishing returns for values > 12.
#       |    |       |  |      
#       \----------------- -T0: use as many threads as you have CPU cores
#            |       |  |      
#            \------------ --force: because the input is not a regular file, zstd want
#                    |  |           to be explicitly told that, yes, we want this.
#                    |  |      
#                    \---- --: afterwards there's file names. Just for good measure.
#                       |      
#                       \- "${devlink}": input filename
```

Couple other remarks:

- Running a backup on an actively, read/write mounted root file system: you can do that, yes, but it'll be in need of repair the very moment you try to restore it. Kind of a bad idea, hence. Do this from a live image, preferably, or `sync; mount -o remount,ro ${root partition} /` before, and `mount -o remount,rw …` after, at least. Yes, that will mess with the operation of your system while the backup is running. But you're not doing a backup to write "some backup somewhere for uncertain purposes", but to have a restorable, reliable state of your machine.
- If you need to do this on a live system, you'd typically have a different approach. You'd use LVM or a snapshotting file system (ZFS, btrfs) for your root and data volumes instead, would do a snapshot, and back up that snapshot. **If** I guess correctly from your partial partition list, your system isn't even set up to use LVM, that's really annoying (nobody wants to deal with raw partitions in 2023! this isn't the 90s.) for you. Consider reinstalling your system to use either LVM or btrfs or ZFS.
- You're writing your backup to an NTFS volume. Linux NTFS drivers are probably less reliable than they should be for backups. Also, ntfs-3g is slow! So, you'd crank up the compression ratio (your `gzip` **must** use `-9` / `--best`, and your `zstd` would tend towards `-12` to `-14`) in expense of compression speed, because you'd mostly be limited by write speed, not compression speed, anyways, and writing less makes things

  - more reliable, because fewer bits written means fewer chances for mistakes, and
  - faster, since fewer bits to write, less to wait

Comment: Have you created the ASCII tree in the comments with the details of each argument manually from scratch, or is there a tool that helps with that?

Comment: @aviro manually, but I've very much considered making this a quick python script

Comment: hi I  tried the script. Seems good but I think it writes the output file to /dev/disk/by_id folder instead of the desired folder. Maybe I copied something wrong.
The script is:

`#!/bin/sh
devlink=/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x50000f0000000000
zstd -12 -T2 --force -- "${devlink}" > /mnt/5E13119070E2D202/Backups/system_drive.backup.img.gz
`
and after running it, it creates a 0  size file in `/mnt/5E13119070E2D202/Backups/system_drive.backup.img.gz` and a 1.7gig file in `/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x50000f0000000000.zst`

Comment: @vzografos you are right, from the man pages of `zstd`: _"Unless `--stdout` or `-o` is specified, files are written to a new file whose name is derived from the source file name:  o   When compressing, the suffix .zst is appended to the source filename to get the target filename"._ So just add `--stdout` to the command. And you can delete the `.zst` file that was created.

Comment: ah right, my mistake

Comment: And it's actually better to use the `-o FILE` argument, because than it would write (by default) sparse file, which is smaller and a bit faster.

Comment: You can be sure the output of a compressor will never be sparse, @aviro

Comment: Right, sorry, this only affects decompression.